# get line from file and use as regular expression(regex)

Tags: c++, regex, file, boost, iostream

I made a file(.txt) to put regular expression.
Each line contain one regex, I want to read regex from file and then make a regex like `boost::regex exp(line);` that `line` stand for regex that I got it from file.
I use function `regex_search(text, what, exp)` to match exp in text. but it doesn't match, When I straight use `boost::regex exp("((?<destination_ip>\\S+)?)");` it match clearly.
so how can I get line from file and use as `boost::regex exp(line);`?

---

my code that stream to file is:

```
using namespace boost;
ifstream rgxFile("regex.txt", ios::in);
smatch what;

while(getline(rgxFile, line))
{    
    regex exp(line);
    if( regex_search(text, what, exp) )
    {
        cout<<"destination IP: "<<what["destination_ip"]<<" ";   
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Nothing Found.";
    }
}
```

I think something's wrong with reading file and get line!

Update:

There is a log file that show accessed to web site. i.e. this is one line of log file:

```
  192.168.1.9
```

(it contain another things, But that's enough).

I want to get IPs and use them. That regex is good, But some of line contain something that didn't match.

So I need a text file contain many regexes. If one of text line didn't match, use another regex to match it.

All regex matches all of text file(log.txt). but when I put regex into the file and read them, it doesn't match any thing.

This is exactly regex in regex.txt :

```
((?<destination_ip>\\S+)?)(\\s[+-]){2} \\[(?<timestamp>\\d{2}\/\\w{3}\/\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s+[+-]\\d{4}\\] \"(?<referer_uri>.*)\"<br/>
```

This is one line of access file(log.txt):

```
192.168.1.9 - - [20/Apr/2014:07:46:19 -0400] "GET /dvwa/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0"
```

Comment: doesn't match to text string

Comment: First step, then, is to determine that your string is actually correct...

Comment: yeah, when straightly use, It match correctly

Comment: you can print line and check whether correct or not

Comment: Why are you doing this in C++? Have you considered using a single regex (`(?<destination_ip>('\\d+\\.){3}\\d+|bogus)` to match an IP as well as 'bogus')? I smell [a XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wait. So... now you are saying you have `<br/>` in your regex.txt?

Comment: I've updated my answer for the specific examples you gave. Still, it looks like you're trying to write a log analyzer and I'd strongly advise you to use existing software for this (your approach will **not** be reliable let alone scale) or at least write it in e.g. Python or Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the file contains

```
((?<destination_ip>\S+)?)
```

and not, e.g.

```
"((?<destination_ip>\\S+)?)"
```

You /might/ also add the `std::ios::binary` flag to the istream.

**EDIT** With the extra information from the OP, here's a simple proof that it works: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/080fa6fd73cf70a9])**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;
    std::ifstream rgxFile("regex.txt", ios::in);
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");

    std::string line, text;
    while (getline(input, text))
    {
        while(getline(rgxFile, line))
        {    
            smatch what;
            regex exp(line);
            if (regex_search(text, what, exp))
            {
                std::cout << "destination IP: " << what["destination_ip"] << " ";
            } else
            {
                std::cout<<"Nothing Found.\n";
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Prints

```
destination IP: 192.168.1.9
```

When input.txt is:

```
192.168.1.9 - - [20/Apr/2014:07:46:19 -0400] "GET /dvwa/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0"
```

And regex.txt:

```
((?<destination_ip>\S+)?)(\s[+-]){2} \[(?<timestamp>\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+[+-]\d{4}\] "(?<referer_uri>.*)"
```

> **CAVEAT** *As you can see, **[indeed you had too many `\` escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670901/get-line-from-file-and-use-as-regular-expressionregex/24671838#comment38260095_24671838)** (input.txt is not a C++ string literal) and the fact that you had managed the `<br/>` at the end makes me doubt that you should be doing this, let alone in c++.*

Comment: No, It doesn't match anything and ios::binary not working too.

Comment: Which completely bypasses the question posed. Did you check the file contents? Perhaps it is time to _show_ what you are using

Comment: In c++, Regex ((?<destination_ip>\S+)?) must have double backslash like \\S+

Comment: Again, you sidestepped the actual answer to the question. The point is, in the file you **don't** need the double backslash. (_You can't answer a question, by saying something "true" about something else_)

Comment: Sorry if I judged too soon, but I tried very much and it doesn't match with one backslash.

Comment: @AiPdimi you're wasting our time until you show what exactly is in that file, `regex.txt`.

Comment: @AiPdimi I've shown working code now. It's essential that you get the levels of quoting and escaping right.

Comment: @AiPdimi As off-topic as this is, it's also wrong. I voted /up/ at [08:33Z](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24671838/85371) and then down at [13:52Z](http://tinyurl.com/mn3yts8#comment38262400_24671838). that's more than 6 hours of patience. And I even waited for ~1.5 hours after you [promised to edit](http://tinyurl.com/kea9kjm#comment38260158_24671838) and I had to check back regularly to find [this edit at the time](http://tinyurl.com/okwrrvh) which I [even edited for you](http://tinyurl.com/m34b5fm). So I think you're a bit out of line accusing me of premature downvoting.

Comment: Note that ironically, my immediate answer _was correct_ and I indeed wasted a lot of time after that. So, downvoting was in order (bad questions should be downvoted). That all said, with the latest edit I can un-downvote it. [Done]